# "worth to be verb-ed" vs. "worth verb-ing"

Tags: verbs, past-participles

> I read somewhere that Kynesian theory was contradicted, and therefore **worth to be abandoned**, ... 
>   —Dorigo G., in a [comment](http://krugman.blogs.nytimes.com/2008/11/28/was-the-great-depression-a-monetary-phenomenon/#comment-71231) on Paul Krugman's blog

My grammar book says that this sentence is wrong:

> The car isn't **worth to be repaired**.

Whereas, this sentence is correct:

> The car isn't **worth repairing**.

But in Dorigo G.'s sentence, the clause **worth to be abandoned** is used and this clause seems to have the same structure of **worth to be repaired**—e.g.,"worth to be *verb*-ed".

Is Dorigo G. wrong? Or are there differences between the grammar under his sentence and the grammar under the example sentences reported by my book?

Comment: I think it's just a "typo". Perhaps he meant to write *isn't worth **being repaired*** (which still isn't great, but at least it's not so glaringly unacceptable as what he actually ended up with).

Comment: This quote is from a [comment](http://krugman.blogs.nytimes.com/2008/11/28/was-the-great-depression-a-monetary-phenomenon/#comment-71231) on Paul Krugman's blog.  The man himself said no such thing.  Note that blog comments are not, as a rule, proofread and are likely to contain typos like these.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is just a matter of a typo in the sentence you read in the NY Times. It should have read:

> I read somewhere that Kynesian theory was contradicted, and therefore **worthy** to be abandoned, ...

When something is said to be "worthy to be [x]", the statement is that the object possesses the innate qualities to deserve [x] happening to it.  In this specific case it's not actually a positive statement, but an example of a way it might be used positively is:

> The question was well-asked and provoked interesting answers. It was definitely **worthy** of the  Nice Question badge.

Now when you say that the car isn't *worth repairing*, that's a little bit different.  What you're saying is that it will not be a good use of your time/money/other expenditures required to fix the car for whatever reason.  An example could be that it would cost $2000 to fix the car, but only $1500 to buy another car instead.  So in this context, "[Object] is not worth [verb]-ing" means "It will be a waste of your [time/resources] to [verb] the [object]."

Comment: +1 Actually, if OP's reporting is correct there's another typo: it should be *Keynesian*.